# CSS for div class isn't working-why?

Tags: html, css

I wonder why the css for the div class=iphone isn't working-you can't see a border or anything else I include in the css..however when I was writing the code on codepen it all worked just fine and once I did it on sublime, it won't show anything (but only for the div element with the class iphone). Does anyone know why? Thanks!!
Html:

```
 <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Guess a Number!</h1>
      <h2> - - - - - - - - - - - - -</h2>
      <h3>Lets Play</h3>
      <h4>Pick a number from 1-100</h4>
    </header>
    <section>
    <div class="iphone"> ..
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="number"   
  class=pickingNumber> 
        <button class="send"><i class="fa fa-share"></i></button> 
      </div>
      <div class="playAgain">
        <button class="buttons">
          <p><b>---</b></p>
        </button>
        <button class="buttons">
          <p><b>---</b></p>
        </button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <div>
      <p class="end">&copy; Made by me</p>
      <p class="end">Thanks for visiting!</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

part of css for that:

```
.iphone{
    border: 6px solid #949599;

}
```

Comment: In chrome/chromium or Firefox with Firebug installed, inspect the element and see which css rules are being applied to the div.

Comment: I don't know whether that has to do with your problem, but in `class=pickingNumber` inside the ìnput` tag inside  that `iphone` div, the quotation signs are missing (should be `class="pickingNumber"`)

Answer (score 0):

Does your HTML have a `<link>` to the css file?

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra div in the footer it seems. That may be a problem? There are precedential rules too, so make sure that iphone class is the last class loaded with that name.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give the iphone class some dimensions.

`iphone {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}`